# How to integrate a public Tableau dashboard into a responsive web design theme?

Tags: responsive-design, dashboard, responsive, tableau-api

I did some research on trying to find on how to integrate dashboards like tableau into a responsive web design sites. Couldn't find much help.

This is my [tableau dashboard](https://public.tableau.com/profile/shiva.shinde#!/vizhome/Orzota/Story1) on tableau public server. I have my javascript embed code working and ready of this public dashboard.

I need to put this dashboard into a responsive design theme [SB Admin 2 - Free Bootstrap Admin Theme](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) I am stuck, where do I start from? do I have to put/replace this in index.html, or any js files?

This theme already has a dashboard, shall I remove it or replace it to put this tableau dashborad into it?

Answer (score 0):

You will  want to check out the "device designer" and "device preview" features in Tableau 10. The big idea is that can build separate versions of your dashboard for different sizes of display. Tableau Server (or Tableau Public) will automatically serve up the right version depending on the users' displays.

Here's a blog posting that will explain the details: http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/6/device-designer-56018

The other thing you might find useful is Tableau's JSAPI. You can drive various aspects of an Tableau viz embedded inside a web page with Javascript. Here's some of the basics: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm Here's a intro video (registration is required) for the JSAPI: http://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/javascript-api-intro-and-embed